FadeSplashScreenDuration delay not working
Increasing/decreasing the FadeSplashScreenDuration in config.xml for an ionic project doesn't impact the duration in which the splash screen is displayed for
Splash screen related code
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />

Ionic project plugin ( ionic cordova plugin list)
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"

